# Count Unique values in array of arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array of arrays

```
push @fail_codes,[$r->[5],$row->[1]];
```

that looks like that

```
STRING_1, VALUE_1

STRING_1, VALUE_1

STRING_1, VALUE_2

STRING_1, VALUE_3

STRING_2, VALUE_1

STRING_2, VALUE_1

STRING_2, VALUE_2
```

I don't know in advance the FC strings neither the values.

What I would like to do is to count the items in the way that I get

STRING_1 was found n times with values VALUE_1

STRING_1 was found n times with values VALUE_2

STRING_2 was found n times with values VALUE_3 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my %seen;
$seen{"$_->[0] was found %d times with value $_->[1]"}++ for @fail_codes;

printf("$_\n", $seen{$_}) for sort keys %seen;
```